# FODM3083 + Q6016NH2 switching 230V and 110V up to 16A

Tags: triac

I have to be able to switch on and off a heater of 1500W total powered at 110AC and 230AC but I have some additional doubts.
First doubt is about the proposed FODM design for hot-line switch (https://hr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FODM3083_D-1809422.pdf), page 7:

minimum calculated resistor on triac side shall be 191Ohm so I'll stay with 360Ohm on pin 4 and 330Ohm on pin 3. Power required of the resistors is 8.5mW so 1/4W will do. Is that correct?

My second doubt is about how much copper pad area is required for effective heat dissipation of the triac. Here I have been looking at triac manual: https://hr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/240/Littelfuse_Thyristor_Qxx15xx_Qxx16xHx_Datasheet_pd-775524.pdf and an Philips "guide" for triac dissipation: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1760767.pdf

All together, I have been calculated: It(rms)=13, It(avg)=11.7, V0=1.1, Rs=0.01, Ta=60, Tj=125

Total power:

```
P=V0*It(avg)+Rs*It(rms)=15.73
```

Thermal calculation:

```
Rth(total)=(Tj-Ta)/P=4.13degc/W
Rth(j-case)=1.7degC/W
Rth(extra)=4.13-1.7=2.43degC/W
```

As written in Philips AN, page 11.:"As an approximate guide, this thermal resistance (49degC/W) can be obtained with a copper pad area of 500 mm2..." meaning that I would require:

```
2.43*500/49=24.79mm2
```

of copper pad area to effectively keep triac working.
Is all this OK or I did some mistake in the calculations? It seems a little small area to me... Thanks.

Gabrijel

Comment: Your ratio assumes W/C, the 49 figure is C/W, so the ratio has to go the other way up, 500 * 49 / 2.43 = 10000 mm2. But it doesn't just scale as a copper pad. The thermal impedance of copper foil will be too high in the vicinity of the package, so you need thicker foil, much, much thicker, or, you know, a proper heatsink, which is thick under the package at that power level.

Comment: You really should have more margin on your triac current. And if you do run near the maximum, you usually need ideal conditions (really big heatsink).

Comment: Well, it looked to good to be true so I was sure that I calculated something wrong. Thanks for pointing me into the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the formula in 1.1.2 of [this app note](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/smdpack.pdf?fileId=db3a304330f6860601311905ea1d4599), I came up with 14.56W which, while slightly lower, doesn't solve your problem.  As @Neil_UK pointed out, the copper area scales the other way, so you would need more than 500mm^2 to get to your required Rth(case-ambient).  The junction max temperature is 125C and you're starting from 60C so with a Rth(j-c) of 1.7C/W, you are looking for a Rth(c-a) of 2.75C/W to keep your junction below 100C, which is what I'd recommend for design factor.

From equation 10 of [this app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva419c/snva419c.pdf?ts=1664347356830), you will need 525*cm*^2 of copper to hit your target Rth(c-a).  This number is probably lower than the actual value, as effectiveness of additional copper drops off with distance from the heat source, and the edge of this massive pour is almost 12cm from your case.

You need a full-size heatsink for this. Have you considered using a solid-state relay?  For comparison, this is what a 2.7C/W SSR heatsink looks like, that's a DIN rail mounting bracket for scale, the heatsink is 81mm x 45mm x 75mm.
[image: SSR heatsink]

Image source: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Crydom%20PDFs/HS271_Series.pdf

Comment: Yes, I agree: With so big heatsink required, I'll just have to use either mechanical relay or SSR. As this is a redesign of a working device (currently with mechanical relays) it might be possible to measure actual current and peak current then decide if SSR is OK or too big (by dimensions) and use mechanical one.

Comment: SSRs are pretty cheap, I think with a 20A relay/heatsink combination you could be all done for $50 or $60.

Comment: I only worked with G3MB-202P SSR for AC switching. I have found similar case size "SSR" for 6A or 10A but it looks like they are actually mechanical devices. Anyway, for higher currents, SSR are "cube" size like Omron G3NA series?

Comment: I think they call them "hockey puck" style SSRs though they are in a rectangular case.  They also make (and I recommend for this application) SSRs with a heatsink already attached, which is itself either chassis mount or more commonly DIN rail mount.  That saves you the trouble of finding an appropriate heatsink and properly mounting it (thermal interface material, torque values, etc).